# I can't access to my object's array's values for some reason

Tags: javascript, json

I have an object, and I want to log the `values` array but when I do so, the array is empty. Why is that?

```
var data = {"values" : []};
   Papa.parse('data.csv', {
    header: true,
    download: true,
    newline: "\n",
    quoteChar : '',
    escapeChar : '',
    chunk: function(results) {
            data.values.push(results.data);
    },
});
console.log(data);
console.log(data.values.length); // 0
console.log(data.values[0]); // undefined
```

Comment: You do not have a JSON there. You have an *object*. JSON is a *method of formatting a string to represent an object*.

Comment: Post the (fuller, reproducible) code in question. Sounds like you're not waiting for the object to be populated before you're trying to log it.

Comment: thanks for the reply : I already get that "data" is an object and not a String, maybe i'm wasn't exact when i talked about it

Comment: What point in the script are you invoking console.log(); ?

Comment: it's just to know what happened actually, it wont be there when my work will be over

Comment: what you see in console is not a snapshot. When you populate the arrays **after** you log the object to console the console will reflect all updates since it is a live object

Comment: thanks for the information i didn't knew that ; but in this case the array is populate before the log

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Papa.parse` is asynchronous; currently, you're logging the data *only after you've send the command to parse the CSV*, but the response hasn't come back yet; the callback hasn't triggered. you need to add a `complete` handler [as described in the docs](https://www.papaparse.com/docs).

```
Papa.parse('data.csv', {
  header: true,
  download: true,
  newline: "\n",
  quoteChar : '',
  escapeChar : '',
  chunk: function(results) {
    data.values.push(results.data);
  },
  complete: function() {
    console.log('done');
    console.log(data.values[0]);
  }
});
```

Comment: You are my savior buddy, that was totally that problem, didn't think of that.